# passing a parameter in a while loop

Tags: bash

I have tried adding a $1 to the variable but it does not work.
this is what I have so far.
Do i have to add anything else to the variable so it works

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
dir=" "
MODEL="UNKNOWN : $1"
while [ "$MODEL" = "UNKNOWN" ]; do
    KIND="UNKNOWN"
    echo -n "Enter kind [x|y]: "
    read K
    UPPER="$(echo ${K}|tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')"
   case "$UPPER" in
        x) MODEL="x" ;;
        y) MODEL="y" ;;
    esac
 done

if [ "$MODEL" == "x" ]; then
    echo "Preparing to installation x applications...."
    cd hpcld
    dir="$(pwd)"
    echo $dir
    echo "./install_x.sh"
else
    echo "Preparing to installation y applications...."
    cd hbcb
    dir="$(pwd)"
    echo $dir
    echo "./install_y.sh"
fi
```

Comment: Where do you use variable `KIND`?

Comment: Can you show with an additional `echo` which line gives a problem? I just don't know where to start helping you: `echo "${MODEL}"` after the first assignment, the `case "$UPPER" in` where you compare this with lowercase values, or should I show you the variable  `${PWD}`? Perhaps you want `MODEL=${1:-UNKNOWN}`, but this will only work when `$1` is `x` or `y`.

Comment: I think that will work

Comment: I will work on it and update it soon

Comment: what is in `$1`?  if this is supposed to be some sort of 'model' then try `MODEL="${1:-UNKNOWN}"`; consider `typeset -u K; read -r -p "Enter kind [x|y]: " K` (to replace the `echo/read/UPPER=` tuple) ... then `case "${K}" in ...`, but also need to define your cases as **UPPPER**, too => `X)...;; Y)...;;`; I would also suggest getting out of the habit of using variables with uppercase names (OS variables are uppercase and if you're not aware of all OS variables you run the risk of either a) overwriting a system variable or b) the OS overwriting your variable)